# Change Kubernetes docker-for-desktop cluster network ip

Tags: docker, networking, kubernetes

I am trying to configure Kubernetes on docker-for-desktops and I want to change the default network assigned to containers.

> Example: the default network is `10.1.0.0/16` but I want `172.16.0.0/16`.

I changed the docker network section to `Subnet address:  172.16.0.0 and netmask 255.255.0.0` but the cluster keeps assigning the network 10.1.0.0/16. 
[image: Network configuration]

The problem I am facing here is that I am in a VPN which has the same network IP of kubernetes default network (`10.1.0.0/16`) so if I try to ping a host that is under the vpn, the container from which I am doing the ping keeps saying `Destination Host Unreachable`.

I am running Docker Desktop (under Windows Pro) Version 2.0.0.0-win81 (29211) Channel: stable Build: 4271b9e.

Kubernetes is provided from Docker desktop [image: Kuberbetes]

From the official [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/kubernetes/) I know that

> Kubernetes is available in Docker for Windows 18.02 CE Edge and higher, and 18.06 Stable and higher , this includes a standalone Kubernetes server and client, as well as Docker CLI integration. The Kubernetes server runs locally within your Docker instance, **is not configurable**, and is a single-node cluster

Said so, should Kubernetes  use the underlying docker's configuration (like network, volumes etc.)?

Comment: Could you add more information about your cluster configuration, e.g. which network add-on do you use? And what installer for Kubernetes did you use?

Comment: added more information @ArtemGolenyaev thanks

Comment: I'm not sure about such Kubernetes installation for Windows, usually Kubernetes uses not only Docker network but also network add-on. Here is the list  https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/addons/ It is possible that you need to look deeper for such settings

Comment: I'm struggling with exactly the same problem (but on MacOS), so if you figured out anything to fix it, I'm happy to hear :)

Comment: Any news on this? cc @SaskiaKeil  :)

Comment: @fr4nk Unfortunately not. I learnt that more colleagues in my company (= in my network) struggle with that, but we couldn't find a way to make it work. In our team we now have the suboptimal setup that we use docker-compose locally and if we need to test anything with Kubernetes we deploy to the cluster directly.

Comment: @SaskiaKeil thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @SaskiaKeil  Unfortunately I could not manage to solve this. So instead of using docker for desktop I am using Kubeadm (single master node cluster) on my dev environment.

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes also has a subnet that it uses and a corresponding network setting, which defaults to `10.1.0.0/16`, but this setting is not exposed in the Docker for-win UI. In [docker/for-win issue #1667: Can not access local network, with kubernetes installed](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1667#issuecomment-367357067), guillaumerose shows a workaround that I've altered a bit to read:

1. Disable Kubernetes
2. Restart Docker for-win to clicking on "Restart" from the "Troubleshoot" screen (the one with the bug icon) - this step is missing in guillaumerose's workaround, see below
3. `docker run -it --privileged --pid=host justincormack/nsenter1` and edit `/var/lib/cni/conf/10-default.conflist`. Change the mentioned `10.1.0.0/16` to the network you want. Don't forget the gateway and the dns
4. Enable Kubernetes

In step 3, I changed `/var/lib/cni/conf/10-default.conflist` like this:

```
# diff -u 10-default.conflist.orig 10-default.conflist
--- 10-default.conflist.orig
+++ 10-default.conflist
@@ -10,11 +10,11 @@
       "hairpinMode": true,
       "ipam": {
         "type": "host-local",
-        "subnet": "10.1.0.0/16",
-        "gateway": "10.1.0.1"
+        "subnet": "10.250.0.0/16",
+        "gateway": "10.250.0.1"
       },
       "dns": {
-        "nameservers": ["10.1.0.1"]
+        "nameservers": ["10.250.0.1"]
       }
     },
     {
```

And this works. I can now ping `10.1.119.43` *and* use kubernetes.

### OBS! `10-default.conflist` gets reset/reverted whenever docker is restarted

Yes, every time docker gets restarted (e.g. because of a windows reboot), kubernetes reverts back to using `10.1.0.0/16` and then it is broken again. Apply the workaround above once more, and it will work again.

So I personally have a `~/10-default.conflist.250` file with the above patch applied and then do:

```
docker run -i --rm --privileged --pid=host justincormack/nsenter1 /bin/sh -c '/bin/cat > /var/lib/cni/conf/10-default.conflist' < ~/10-default.conflist.250
```

as step 3 above instead of editing the file by hand over and over.

It is quite annoying that this the workaround has to be applied every time docker for-win is restarted, but it is better than it not working :-).

### About the need to restart Docker for-win after disabling kubernetes

My experience is that when kubernetes has been restarted and has reverted to using `10.1.0.0/16`, if I skip step 2 - the "restart Docker for-win" step - it takes more then 5 minutes to attempt to start kubernetes after which I give up waiting. When I now restart docker (because kubernetes is in a bad state), kubernetes will be re-enabled (again using `10.1.0.0/16`) but now I can follow the workaround again (including step 2). So restarting docker between disabling kubernetes and modifying `10-default.conflist` makes the subsequent start of kubernetes actually work.

If anybody has any idea why the contents of `/var/lib/cni/conf/10-default.conflist` revert to factory defaults every time docker gets restarted, I'm very curious to understand why that is and how to fix this last annoying problem.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, edit this file for a permanent fix:

```
%AppData%\Docker\cni\10-default.conflist
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending time investigating my other answer, a colleague suggested:

> Why bother with the kubernetes built-in to Docker for-win at all?
>
> Why not just use ["kind"](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/) - kubernetes-in-docker?

```
brew install kind
kind create cluster

# Cluster is ready for use:
kubectl --context kind-kind get -A pods
```

Boom! Kubernetes running in 20 seconds. The entire one-node kubernetes cluster is running inside a single docker container. I don't think I'm ever going back...

Answer (score -1):

Did you restart docker-for-desktop or your entire computer? And do you see those new network settings in the docker network adapter it should have created on your computer?
If those network changes are not reflected on the virtual network adapter on your computer, then those changes somehow did not applied. Try uninstalling docker-for-desktop or the kubernetes service.

If that virtual network does have those changes, or maybe a second network adapter has been created on your computer for kubernetes, you might want to reinstall the kubernetes service. Kubernetes uses network specific configuration, which it got when installing the service.