# Enabling Kubernetes on Docker Desktop breaks access to external service

Tags: docker, networking, kubernetes, kubectl, docker-desktop

I'm using docker desktop for mac.

I have built a docker image for a Node.js app that connects to an external MongoDB database via URI (the db is running on an AWS instance that I'm connected to over vpn). This works fine - I run the container and the app can connect to the database. Happy days.

**Then...**

I enable Kubernetes on docker desktop. I apply a `deployment.yml` to run the container but this deployment fails when trying to connect to the db. From my app's logs (I'm using mongoose):

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect EHOSTUNREACH [MY DB IP] +30005ms
```

**Interestingly...**

I can now no longer connect to the db by running my docker container either. I get the same error.

I have to disable kubernetes, restart docker desktop (twice), prune my previous container and network, and re-run my container. Then it will work again.

As soon as I enable kubernetes again, the db becomes unreachable again.

**Any ideas why this is and/or how to fix it?**

Comment: mongodb is running  in same system or remote system?

Comment: remote, accessible over vpn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue for us turned out to be an IP range clash. Exactly the same as described in this SO question:

[Change Kubernetes docker-for-desktop cluster network ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53590312/change-kubernetes-docker-for-desktop-cluster-network-ip)

Unfortunately, like this user, we haven't been able to find a solution

Comment: I've added an answer for [Change Kubernetes docker-for-desktop cluster network ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53590312/change-kubernetes-docker-for-desktop-cluster-network-ip/68658242#68658242) - Does that answer work for macs too?